# NachOS + Eclipse debugging issues

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, nachos

Hey guys I'm trying to set up a nachos project in Eclipse on my ubuntu machine. I meticulously followed the instructions here:

http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/fa06/Nachos/eclipse/#nachosfs

It runs fine, but when I set a breakpoint and hit debug I get:

```
New_configuration [Java Application]    
    nachos.machine.Machine at localhost:54060   
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
            ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(String) line: not available [native method]  
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).findBootstrapClass0(String) line: 898  
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 314   
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 312   
            Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 294    
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 264    
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClassInternal(String) line: 332    
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java (Feb 15, 2010 12:44:38 AM)
```

Any Giants with some extra shoulder space out there? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the breakpoints out, ran the project in debug mode without any breakpoints with no problem, now it's stopping at the breakpoints properly... go figure.